# Menu open event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF menu which I add items to programatically. It consist of a couple of MenuItems. 
However, in one of the menuitems I add a ListBox.(I needed a scroller because we have many items and that made it easy).

The menu looks fine and works. The problem is that after I select (click on) something on the ListBox the menu closes as expected; but if I move the mouse over it, the menu pops open. 
I have searched all over the internet with no luck which is not surprising since it is pretty custom stuff.

The last thing I tried was checking the events and see if I can handle them. I can detect the `MouseOver`. However I do not see any `PopOpen` or `OnClick` event for the menu.

Any ideas if I can detect these events? Any other ideas, suggestions would be appreciated. And if there is a way to add a scroller to a bunch of MenuItems then I may change my design as well.

Comment: [Should I use tags in my question title ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). No you should noté

Comment: @Luis Garcia Its possible that if you are not seeing the events that the control itself is consuming/handling them. In the parent control where you add the items have you tried doing something to get even handled events like this: lstbx.AddHandler(the routed event here, the callback handler, true)

Comment: Please add a small yet complete example of your code